# Xcode6 Beta6 : this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Tags: ios, swift

Just having textField named "IBtextFieldName", which already hooked in Xib & proper class is assigned to File's Owner, But keep getting

```
'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7fb9cc81acd0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key IBtextFieldName
```

Already Tried:

- Clean build,
- Removed derived data,
- Open Xib as source code and remove un-needed connections,
- Removed and re-created xib and associated .swift class file,
- Removed and re-created UITextfield and outlet with different name,
- Restarted Xcode

Comment: Check you UIViewController code and xib file, maybe, they contain invalid connections

Comment: I have confirmed that, and even there is no missing connection with (!) sign in xib

Comment: delete IBtextFieldName reference  in xib and hook it up again

Comment: @akashivskyy: Updated question with answer

Comment: @BaSha If the question might help future visitor please post the answer as answer. If you don't think it will help anybody delete your question.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED:**

was silly mistake

were using,

```
let myController : MyController = UIViewController(nibName: "MyController", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()) as MyController
```

instead

```
let myController : MyController = MyController(nibName: "MyController", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()) as MyController
```